# Read object data from externel file into const object1

Tags: javascript, arrays, pure-js

Instead of having the data array in the js-file I would like to read the "Object data" from an external file.

```
const object1 = {
        Day_1:89,
        Day_2:80,
        Day_3:78,
        Day_4:83,
        Day_5:89,
        Day_6:89,
        Day_7:80,
        Day_8:78,
        Day_9:78,
        Day10:83,
        Day11:89,
        Day12:80,
        Day13:78,
        Day14:83
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `fetch`?

Comment: Have you considered to use JSON file ? it can be a good practise. let us  know if you need help on that way

Comment: let data = getText("fetch_info.txt");

async function getText(file) {
  let myObject = await fetch(file);
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(myObject)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
return myObject;
}